# JSON format : which array structure is better or correct?

Tags: php, json

I want to ask about the JSON format. The results of Sql is

```
Year SumOfYear
2011 0.30
2012 0.19
```

#### update

this is the part of php code.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {

  $results[] = array(
     '"Year"' => $row['Year'],
     '"SumOfYear"' => $row['SumOfYear'],
     );

 }

echo json_encode($results);
```

The results is

```
[

{
Year: "2011",
SumOfYear: "0.30"
},

{
Year: "2012",
SumOfYear: "0.19"
}

]
```

if i want to have like below, is it still good format?

```
{
 2011,
 2012
},
{
 0.30,
 0.19
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the JSON code is the original, you have to put `Year` and `SumOfYear` between code signs:

```
[
   {
      "Year":"2011",
      "SumOfYear":"0.30"
   },
   {
      "Year":"2012",
      "SumOfYear":"0.19"
   }
]
```

If you want to verify your JSON, you can use [this tool](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com).

As you seem to use `php`, i recommend to structure your data in an array and let `php` [encode it](https://www.php.net/json_encode) into json:

```
echo json_encode(my_data_array);
```

Comment: thanks! that link is useful! what about second structure? is it wrong?

Comment: the second has the same syntax error: `"Year"` and `"SumOfYear"`, and the syntax error, as you miss a `comma` between the object. But has an additional error: You can't have two objects with the same `Key` on the same layer. So there can only be one object with `key` year and the same for the `key` SumOfYear on the other layer.
This will cause either an parsing error, or a loss of information.

Comment: Thanks. I updated it. can you tell second structure is good or bad? @lootsch